# How can I, per server, create settings with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to add per server a settings command so in one server they could do `^showsettings`

and it would show the settings and then they could do 
`^settings welcome-message false` and there wouldn't be a welcome message when someone joined

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to use database, personnaly, I am most familiar with sqlite3 or mySQL. So first you will need to create some database and table in it. Then when you use the settings command, update the row in database for the server. And when you are doing some operation, query the settings from the database.